# Detecting when applicationDidBecomeActive in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

We are trying to detect when the app becomes active again after being in background mode, we want to be able to fire a method when this occurs. It's such a simple idea: there's even a MonoBehavour method OnApplicationPause which can be used as the app enters background mode, but non for "OnApplicationResume".

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationFocus.html just took 5 seconds looking at the MonoBehaviour class help...

Comment: It means becoming active or unactive, what you can translate to paused or resumed.

Comment: @Gusman The problem is that I don't want the method to fire on the first time the app starts!

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: add a bool, and check for first execution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tryed [OnApplicationFocus](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationFocus.html) and it works fine.

```
bool initialFocus;


void OnApplicationFocus(bool focusStatus)
{
    if (focusStatus)
    {
        //App became active, will fire on application first focus
    }

    if (focusStatus && initialFocus)
    {
        //App became active, after it's been inactive at least once
    }

    initialFocus = initialFocus || focusStatus;
}
```

Further, in your question you ask about `OnApplicationPause`

Note that in fact `OnApplicationPause` detects both pause and unpause in the same way - it gets a bool as an argument.

```
  void OnApplicationPause(bool p)
  {
      Debug.Log("The app just " + (p ? "paused" : "unpaused"));
  }
```

Note too that `OnApplicationQuit` is meaningless on the mobile platforms.