# Check when the user exits the app in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I check when the user exits the app or is in background mode and then fire a method in Unity?

I have tried using:

```
OnApplicationFocus  
OnApplicationPause
OnApplicationQuit
```

I think there must be a "workaround" using the above.

I am creating a mobile game.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because user posted question twice.

Comment: please DON'T post the same question twice in a row. It really wastes the time of moderators.  People will try to help you when they can.  Notice the excellent answers on the other question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting when applicationDidBecomeActive in Unity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35663149/detecting-when-applicationdidbecomeactive-in-unity)

Answer (score 0):

`OnApplicationQuit` is when the user leaves Play mode or closes the executable. That is what you need. But you also might need to tell whether your app is runnning inside Unity editor.

[This page](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-isEditor.html) helps:

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Example()
    {
        if (Application.isEditor)
        {
            print("We are running this from inside of the editor!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do I write `OnApplicationQuit`?

Comment: @JeanMauz inside any `MonoBehaviour` instance.

Comment: I don't the relation of `OnApplicationQuit` with your script. How do I link them?